# Wordpress comment form - display errors on same page (woocommerce ratings)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On my single product page I have activated the ratings form.

Visitors are able to leave a rating which requires the following inputs:

- 1 to 5 stars
- A message
- E-Mail
- Privacy policy checkbox
- Captcha-Code

If any of those fields are missing I get redirected to the default error page from wordpress.

I already tried to create my own validation using jquery -> jquery.validate.js

Based on the information from the [following question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7791/how-to-display-comment-form-error-messages-in-the-same-page).

```
/* Comment form validation on same page */
function comment_validation_init() {
    if (is_single() && comments_open()) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            console.log("ready");
            $('#commentform').validate({
                rules: {
                    author: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    comment: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 20
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    author: "Please enter your name",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
                    comment: "Please enter your comment"
                },
                errorElement: "div",
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    element.after(error);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php

    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'comment_validation_init');
```

After the form submission I still get redirected to the default wordpress error page. (wp-comments-post.php)

[image]

Is there any other way to prevent that from happening and display the errors within the form? (without changing the core files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the form was loaded by Ajax the validation wasn´t working.

As a workaround I triggered my validation through the forms submit button.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#commentform #submit', function(){
    $("#commentform").validate({
        rules: {
            author: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            comment: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 20
            }
        },
        messages: {
            author: "Please enter your name",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
            comment: "Please enter your comment"
        },
        errorElement: "div",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            element.after(error);
        }
   });
}
```

If someone got a "better" solution I would highly appreciate the information.